# Debugger attached. Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webstorm

I'm trying to debug a simple webpack.js file with webstorm and receive the

Here is the code:

```
const GENERATOR = require('ddd-build-configuration/build/webpack.config.generator');
const PATH = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const a= require('./a');
const c= require('./c');

const config = GENERATOR.generate({
    webpack
}, {
    rootPath: PATH.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    aliases: Object.assign({}, a, c)
});

module.exports = config;
```

following error:

```
 "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --inspect-brk=61516 C:\xxx\yyy-zzz-ddd-base-module\build\webpack.config.js
    Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61516/1ca92158-0d53-4c80-a073-5ae97721e783
    For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
    Debugger attached.
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

My settings for javascript ES6 mode 
Using latest version of webstorm 2017.3.5 built on march 2018

Comment: what's the reason for running your webpack config as Node.js application? It's not supposed to be used this way... what are you trtying to debug? Webpack itself, or the application bundled with it?

Comment: I just try to debug this js file and thean how the generate function works ...

Comment: Must I have the --inspect-brk if i'm debugging with node.js + webstorm. isn't this flag is for browser debugging

Comment: `--inspect-brk` is a valid Node.js flag - see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_inspect_brk_host_port

Answer (score -1):

By some configuration changes, following code inserted in app.js

```
import { debuglog } from 'util';
```

I just removed it, now error is gone